# show details row's datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I've got a datatable in a .xhtml page, that shows products of a database.
Let's say that I can only see Name and Code for every row, how can I show more detail of the product in the same page?

Moreover, my product bean is in ViewScope, so i'm not able to show details in another .xhtml page (I've tried many times, but if in case you guys have a solution for this, that's good).

PS: I don't know anything about Javascript yet, so i'd prefer mostly solutions based on jsf and java :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want to display more fields at datatable?
Add more columns..

```
<h:dataTable value="#{pr.products}" var="p">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                    #{p.name}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Code</f:facet>
                    #{p.code}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
                    #{p.price}
                </h:column>
                ........
</h:dataTable>
```

JSF example: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/

If you using primefaces see showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml

**EDIT** 
If you want to make a dialog that shows the details of the selected product see at primefaces showcase the "selection" example.

Comment: lol I didn't mean that, I know how to create columns.
I want something like this (i'll write some options):

1) A button near every product in the datatable, that shows the other details of the product but in the SAME page 

OR 

2) A link near every product that brings to another xhtml page, where there will be all the details for that product. But as I said, my product bean is in viewscoped, so I don't know if this is possible (the parameters won't be saved in that way, if I understood the viewscoped logic well)

Comment: @Enduavon Oh, ok. See the primefaces showcase the "Selection" example. It has a "View" button and shows the details in a dialog. (same page)
link: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: thanks! But i'm not using primefaces. Wondering if I can do it with the basic JSF components...

Comment: And if you want show it in a new page, pass a key on and retrieve it in a new bean. Or start using `@ViewAccessScoped`

Comment: Sure just search the internet, but seach in steps.